# How to read JSON data from Powershell script and iterate through it

Tags: json, powershell, scripting

I'm starting to learn Powershell and I'm currently trying to read in a JSON file.

Here is my JSON file (named 'versions.json'):

```
{
    "versions": {
        "1.0.0": {
            "Component1": "1.0.0",
            "Component2": "1.0.0",
            "Component3": "1.0.0",
        },
        "2.0.0": {
            "Component1": "2.0.0",
            "Component2": "2.0.0",
            "Component3": "2.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to read in this JSON file and print out the versions and what they consist of. For example, 1.0.0 consists of Component 1 at 1.0.0, Component 2 at 1.0.0, and Component 3 at 1.0.0.

I'm currently reading in the JSON file with this Powershell line:

```
$json = (Get-Content "versions.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now, I want to iterate through $json and print out its data. I'm currently using this:

```
foreach($v in $json.versions) {
    echo "Data: $v"
}
```

But, when I run my Powershell script, it prints:

```
Data: @{1.0.0=; 2.0.0=}
```

Is this the proper output? I was expecting to at least see two entries for 1.0.0 and 2.0.0. This feels like it may be a syntax issue but I am unsure. I am using Powershell version 5.

Comment: The '$v' was missing in the original post. I've fixed it.

Comment: It's not a collection, which is why you can't iterate over it. If you do `$json.versions | get-member` you'll see 1.0.0 and 2.0.0 are the properties of a single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using `ConvertFrom-Json` you have a PowerShell object which is a single item that has a `versions` property which has two sub-properties `1.0.0` and `2.0.0`. Your ForEach is attempting to iterate them like a collection, but its just a single object.

However you can iterate over the properties as follows to get the result I think you wanted:

```
 ($Json.versions.psobject.properties) | foreach-object { "Data: $($_.name)" }
```

Comment: When I run your code snippet, I get "cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1. Supply values for the following parameters: Process[0]"

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? That suggests you're missing the scriptblock part (this bit `{ "Data: $($_.name)" }`)

Comment: Hmm, I guess everything has to be on a single line (I moved the "Data:" portion and the brackets down. Now when I run it, I get "Data: " - nothing is there.

Comment: Just the opening `{` needs to be on the same line, you can then add line breaks if you want to.

Comment: My fault - had a typo in my file. Your snippet works properly. I've accepted your answer.